# Meaning of "少し外す"

Tags: definitions

Can "少し外す" mean "zoned out/lost focus"

I can send the source material I read it in, if that helps.

Edit: For those asking for context, here its the bit in the manga:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: 外す in 少し外す can mean at least two quite different things. I think I need the context.

Comment: Yes it helps a great deal.

Comment: **Context is king.**  Consider a question asking what the English word _"net"_ means: it could mean "a thing to catch things in", it could mean "teh intarwebs", it could mean "the amount of money left over after subtracting expenses", among other meanings.  To improve your question, and increase the chances of a useful answer, please include at least the full sentence, ideally even a little bit more before and after.

Answer (score 6):

In this context, 外す means "to leave (for a moment)", "to step out", "to go away from keyboard", etc. See the third definition on jisho.org:

> [image: screenshot]

[席を外す](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B8%AD%E3%82%92%E5%A4%96%E3%81%99) is a common set phrase.

Answer (score 1):

外す is a polite way of saving that one is leaving.  It's more like to excuse oneself.